# Is it possible to hide ribbon controls for specific document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

My requirement is that i have created a custom ribbon control and i want to enable it for specific document library.

Can anyone please guide me for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i think you can do that:
After you created your Action Button(or ribbon control), in "Elements.xml" of your control you need to add "EnabledScript" command to it, like this:

```
  <CustomAction Id="Shakib.EditPermissionForce" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Permission.Modify.Controls._children">
          <Button
              Id="Ribbon.Permission.Modify.PermissionButton"
              Sequence="50"
              Command="ActionPermissionCommand"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/Shakib/images/perm32.png"
              Image16by16="/_layouts/Shakib/images/perm16.png"
              LabelText="Some Label"
              TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="ActionPermissionCommand"
                          EnabledScript="javascript:EnableDoAction();"
                          CommandAction="javascript:DoAction();" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

In "EnabledScript" command you need to specify a logical method which return Boolean, like this:

```
function EnableDoAction() {
    var ids = GetIds();
    return (ids.length > 0);
}
```

In this method you can use all of the SharePoint client object models and verify that if this is the Document library you want.
I think its better to use an external JavaScript file. you can add a reference link to Action Element file("Elements.xml") like this:

```
  <CustomAction
    ScriptSrc="/_layouts/Shakib/dialog.js"
    Location="ScriptLink"
    Sequence="100">
  </CustomAction>
```